# Eliminate unwanted keypoints

Tags: python, image-processing, sift, hough-transform

I would like to eliminate the keypoints detected around the frame of an image (an artwork of a museum gallery ). In other words I want to separate out the actual artwork from its frame. Each artwork consist of different types of frames.

![Keypoints detected using sift][1]

I have already written a Python wrapper for David Lowe's SIFT [implementation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/siftDemoV4.zip) to detect keypoints as well as to compute descriptors.

However my question is what is the best approach to solve this problem? any of the following or something else?

- Using Hough transformation (using Python Image Library)
- Template matching

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Hough transform and try to detect lines which form a quadrilateral.

You might get into trouble if the painting actually does contain a square or something. I'd look for some assumptions like: acceptable aspect ratio, acceptable size. Also find the outermost quadrilateral, and work your way towards the center of the image picking up inner quadrilaterals, if applicable. This would give you the frame and its thickness, so you can disregard any keypoints here or beyond the frame.

P.S. If you got some random replies from me, it's because I accidentally replied to another post in your thread... ^^

Answer (score 0):

*For each artwork, do you have a clean, properly framed reference image?*

If so another solution to remove the *background clutter* is:

1. to use the [**ratio test**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Object_recognition_using_SIFT_features) algorithm to compute keypoints correspondences between your frame and the reference image,
2. to perform a [**geometric consistency check**](http://hal.upmc.fr/docs/00/65/64/34/PDF/valle_doceng09.pdf) to filter out false matches.

In addition the geometric check will provide you with the homography matrix that you can use to warp your input frame or alternatively to project the corners of the reference images.

That way you will natively obtain the artwork area within your frame.

Here's an example about how you can do that with [opensift's match tool](https://github.com/robwhess/opensift/blob/master/src/match.c) - below is an illustration.

[image]

Comment: hi deltheil,+1 thank you for your input, this what something I was looking for,yes I do have a clean image of each artwork. In case suppose if we don't have clean image what would be the approach? I mean say if we have different artworks with different types of frames. Also without a reference image

Comment: This solution is all about pairwise matching (frame vs ref). If you focus on a single frame at once then a self-contained, geometrical approach (e.g Hough) is the way to go.